# Why canvas is not shown correct fill in react component?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a very simple canvas in react component. But canvas is not shown with correct color.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.canvasRef = React.createRef();


  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = this.canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Welcome to Home Page!
        <div className="clearfix"></div>
        <canvas ref={this.canvasRef} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I just seen a default 150*300 default canvas filled in black color. I think I styled it to blue. Why does this happen?

[image: img link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should use `fillStyle` Before before `fillRect`

Your code should be:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works!! I also find another helpful link here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillstyle.asp

Answer (score 1):

@Kareem solution works, but since there is no explanation, here it is:

When you are calling the method `fillRect()` you are telling the canvas to be drawn, so you need to set its properties before drawing it.

As in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect):

> The **`fillRect()`** method draws a filled rectangle whose starting point is
>   at (x, y) and whose size is specified by width and height. The fill
>   style is determined by the current `fillStyle` attribute.

So, if you draw it before setting the `fillStyle`, it's displayed as black.